# Using fullcalendar-scheduler with Angular-Cli project

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am trying to evaluate the use of fullcalendar-scheduler in my Angular 4 project that uses angular-cli.
I have managed to get the fullcalendar core working but have been struggling to get the resources show up in the calendar by using the scheduler.
I was installing the scheduler via npm install fullcalendar-scheduler should do the trick. Added the following to the calendar options but the resources did not show up

```
 resources: [
  { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
  { id: 'b', title: 'Room B' },
  { id: 'c', title: 'Room C' },
  { id: 'd', title: 'Room D' }
],
```

Finally, i tried including the link to the scheduler.min.js in my index.html, and that did the trick. Resources started showing up.
My questions is, how do i make it work without explicitly including link to the scheduler javascript in my index.js?

Comment: Can you please share the code where you have used the full calendar - scheduler?